# Как добавить двумерный список в массив Numpy?

Tags: python, массивы, list, numpy

Имеется двумерный список `s1=[[2,3],[4,5,6]]` и двумерный список `s2=[[7,8,9],[10,11],[12,13]]`. Необходимо в массив `a=np.array([])` добавить данные списки таким образом, чтобы во время итерации по массиву `a` выбирался целиком список `s1` и целиком список `s2`. Аналог данному результату c использованием обычных списков будет выглядеть так:

```
s1=[[2,3],[4,5,6]]
s2=[[7,8,9],[10,11],[12,13]]
s3=[]
s3.append(s1)
s3.append(s2)
for i in s3:
    print(i)
    #[[2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
    #[[7, 8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13]]
```

Если использовать функцию `np.append`, то граница между списками `s1` и `s2` в массиве `a` стирается и все списки и подсписки записывается подряд в одномерный массив:

```
import numpy as np
s1=[[2,3],[4,5,6]]
s2=[[7,8,9],[10,11],[12,13]]
a=np.array([])
a=np.append(a,s1)
a=np.append(a,s2)
for i in a:
    print(i)
    #[2, 3]
    #[4, 5, 6]
    #[7, 8, 9]
    #[10, 11]
    #[12, 13]
```

Таким образом, мне необходим результат как в первом варианте кода, только чтобы данные списков `s1` и `s2` содержались в массиве. Проще говоря, добавить двумерные списки в массив `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что нашел решение своей проблемы в англоязычной версии похожего вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47071845/17715435

```
s1=[[2,3],[4,5,6]]
s2=[[7,8,9],[10,11],[12,13]]
s1=np.array(s1)
s2=np.array(s2)
a=[s1,s2]
a=np.array(a)
for i in a:
    print(i)
    #[list([2, 3]) list([4, 5, 6])]
    #[list([7, 8, 9]) list([10, 11]) list([12, 13])]
```

Answer (score 0):

В официальной документации
Function: Numpy.vstack()

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Не подходит, потому что размерности массивов разные:
a=np.array([[2,3],[4,5,6]]), b = np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11],[12,13]]),  np.vstack((a,b)) ->  ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly